# Automating the creation of postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to automate the creation of a postgres database running on windows 10.
I'd like to be able to start from a default installation of postgres and automate the following steps (not necessarily in this order)

- drop and re-create new database
- drop and re-create new tablespaces
- drop and re-create new users.
- build database objects (tables, views, procedures, triggers etc)
- grant users required permissions.
- populate tables with initial data.

It's not too difficult to reduce this to a series of database commands (so long as they're executed in the correct order) the problem is that for few commands I keep encountering the error 'cannot be issued inside a transaction block'. This means that some commands like DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS and CREATE TABLESPACE can only be run (as far as I can tell) by manually single-stepping them, whereas I can call my table-creation scripts as a single block and re-create a 100 tables in a fraction of a second.

I'm not too worried about the extra few seconds I'm wasting by single-stepping some of the individual commands, but by doing some of it manually I run the risk of missing steps and making mistakes.

How can I automate (i.e. write scripts for) the whole process?

---

Update, script looks a bit like this...

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ????

DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS ????
DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS ????

ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES FROM ????;
ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM ????;

DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;
DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;
DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;

CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';
CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';
CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';

CREATE TABLESPACE fastspace OWNER ???? LOCATION 'c:/????/????';
CREATE TABLESPACE slowspace OWNER ???? LOCATION 'd:/????/????';

DROP DATABASE ????;

CREATE DATABASE ????
  WITH OWNER = ????
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = fastspace
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE ???? TO ????;

COMMENT ON DATABASE ????
  IS '????database';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;

ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO ????;
```

Many (most) of the above commands can be run as part of a transaction block, but a few can't (dropping and creating the database for example).

Comment: What postgres version are you using? How exactly do you execute your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the script with autocommit turned on (the default in `psql`) and use an explicit transaction block for those statements that should run in a single transaction:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ????

DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS ????
DROP TABLESPACE IF EXISTS ????

begin;
  ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES FROM ????;
  ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM ????;

  DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;
  DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;
  DROP USER IF EXISTS ????;

  CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';
  CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';
  CREATE USER ???? PASSWORD '????';
commit;

CREATE TABLESPACE fastspace OWNER ???? LOCATION 'c:/????/????';
CREATE TABLESPACE slowspace OWNER ???? LOCATION 'd:/????/????';

DROP DATABASE ????;

CREATE DATABASE ????
  WITH OWNER = ????
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = fastspace
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

begin;
  GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE ???? TO ????;

  COMMENT ON DATABASE ???? IS '????database';

  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
  GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;
  GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ????;

  ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO ????;
commit;
```